# Securing my ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, .net-security

I'm a bit confused about implementing security in my Web API and would appreciate some guidance.

I'm moving my DAL logic to ASP.NET Web API that I will host as a web role on Azure. This should give me a nice and easy way to scale up independently of my web app.

Currently, this Web API will only be accessed by my ASP.NET MVC 5 front-end but I will definitely add mobile clients to the mix at a later point and they will consume the same data provided by the Web API.

My web app uses Facebook authentication -- and I will continue with that in the mobile app.

How do I handle security in my Web API? The call to the Web API will be made by the MVC app i.e. in an ActionMethod in my controller. What's the best approach to securing my Web API if I'm calling it from my MVC app.

Comment: I assume users of your MVC app will also be authenticated by Facebook?  Just pass along the token to the WebAPI URL...

Comment: I don't want user level authentication. Is there a way to handle authorization like accessing Azure resources where I'd use an access key and a secret code?

Comment: You could pass the Facebook access token on to azure ACS to login to azure